# Bigquery: INTEGER type overflow

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm experiencing problem with INTEGER type. It oveflows and where is no way to prevent it (as it's 64 bit unsigned int). The worst thing it oveflows with no error, just becoming negative number

```
SELECT 9223372036854775807 + 1
```

Is there any possibility to overcome this issue (maybe google has plans to introduce new int types)?

Comment: any BigQuery related real life use case?

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant Aggregating  money stored as nanocents (one of our requirements)

Answer (score 2):

BigQuery will provide an option for SQL to raise error in such cases (integer overflow, division by zero etc)

Comment: Thanks! Do you have any estimations on when it will it be released?

Comment: I hope to see it in production in couple of weeks.

Comment: It is available now, details at https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/sql-reference/enabling-standard-sql

Answer (score 0):

You can detect such conditions and use e.g. NULL as an error indicator, at the cost of more typing.

Something like (assuming you are adding up two non-negative values):

```
select if(a + b >= a, a + b, NULL) from 
(  -- sample data
  select 9223372036854775807 as a, 1 as b
)
```